# How can I leave the item where I left it and have the item not move and stay in the same place?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

When I drop the item it moves to another place and doesn't fit there but I want to place it at those coordinates.

```
const onDrop = (event) => {
    let x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
   
   
    let itemId = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    let item = document.getElementById(itemId).cloneNode(true);

    

    item.style.position = "absolute";
 
    item.style.left = x + 'px';
    item.style.top = y + 'px';
  
    event.target.appendChild(item);
}
```

Comment: Changing the style will make it appear at that position, you don't need to append it as a child.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with this code.

```
const onDrop = (e) => {

var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect(); 
var x = e.clientX - rect.left -30 ; 
var y = e.clientY - rect.top-30; 

let itemId = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
let item = document.getElementById(itemId);

item.style.position = "absolute";

item.style.left = x + 'px';
item.style.top = y + 'px';

e.target.appendChild(item);}
```